# Disable a monitor from multi head

Tags: xrandr

I have a multi head config. I wish do disable one of the screen from cli.

My multi head is configure as a one virtual monitor and the monitors shows the segments of it. Xrandr --off messes up the this layout.

Is there a way to disable a screen and keep the xrandr config of the screen?

Edit: lack of information

Comment: `xrandr --off` would be the normal way to do it. How is the layout messed up? What do you mean by “keep the xrandr config”? What window manager or desktop environment are you using?

Comment: `xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --off` crashes plasma with nvidia driver and ubuntu 15.04